# what is the relative path to asset bundles/packs in react native? (PAD)

Tags: react-native

I have >150mb of assets to load in an Expo react native project. I inserted the bundle manually and it is **successfully** being bundled and delivered on install from PAD (play asset delivery)

**How would I render myImage.png from App.js? What is the relative path? And is there a better more managed way to do this?**

I think expo-assets might be able to help in some way but I'm not sure. If all else fails is there any way to get the file structure of the app, from within the app to explore?

```
android
 ┣ app
 ┣ my_asset_pack
   ┣ src
   ┃ ┗ main
   ┃ ┃ ┗ assets
   ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ myImage.png
   ┗ build.gradle

App.js
```

```
<Image
  source={require('./myImage.png')} //what would the path be?
  style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
></Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide ([faltutech blog article](https://blog.faltutech.com/2023/android/02/13/play-asset-delivery-react-native/)) up to settings.gradle. Then accessed the image via:

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: "asset:/myImage.png" }} //base directory of my_asset_pack/src/main/assets
  style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
></Image>
```

I found this solution digging around [expo file system](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/). There may be a more managed way of doing this (for both expo and non-expo) but this works

Comment: how did you handle dev environments where an APK is being used instead of the bundle? did you differentiate based on environment and use different URIs?

Comment: @PhilHudson I have a fairly manual process. There is definitely a way of automating what I have with build scripts. Also this repo [link] (https://github.com/one-am-it/expo-play-asset-delivery) looks to be the intended solution (it has other install times). However from briefly messing with it I did not get it to work properly, and gave up since I have something that worksish

Comment: assets.js
  `assets['animals']['dog'] = require("../assets/animals/dog.png")`
main.js

``import DEVELOPMENT, ISAPK from "./configs.js"
import assets from "./assets.js"
export const getPlatformImageSource = (folder, resource) => {
  if (Platform.OS === "android" && !DEVELOPMENT && !ISAPK) {
    let uriVar = { uri: `asset:/${folder}/${resource}.png` };
    return uriVar;
  } else {
    try {
      return assets[folder][resource];
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }
  }
}``

Comment: and if you need to be able to search them you can make a dummy version of assets that doesn't actually point to anything. With this system I have to move things around and prebuild using that article. If you do adopt with build scripts please share them as that would help me out a lot!